# java set condition to start with a certain enum value

Tags: java, enums

How can I write a condition in java to check for an enum value that start with `IOS`?

for the following condition it just sets it equal to `IOS` but I want my condition to have my `getSoftwareName()` to startWith `IOS`

```
if (request.getEquipmentInfo().getSoftwareName() == RouterSwName.IOS) {

}
```

Here is my enum class:

```
 public enum RouterSwName   
{
   JUNOS,
   IOS,
   IOS_XR,
   IOS_XE,
   OTHER; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
request.getEquipmentInfo.getSoftwareName().toString().startsWith("IOS")
```

Assuming that `getSoftwareName()` returns an enum, its `toString()` should return raw enum name as `String`. Then you simply check if it starts with "IOS".

Comment: You can use `name()` instead of `toString()`. Both methods return same result, but `name` is more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

you could:

```
if (request.getEquipmentInfo().getSoftwareName() == RouterSwName.IOS ||
    request.getEquipmentInfo().getSoftwareName() == RouterSwName.IOS_XR ||
    request.getEquipmentInfo().getSoftwareName() == RouterSwName.IOS_XE)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* attach a property to each constant, but I would just keep a separate set of them:

```
private static final Set<RouteSwName> IOS_ROUTERS =
    Collections.unmodifiableSet(
        EnumSet.of(
            RouteSwName.IOS,
            RouteSwName.IOS_XR,
            RouteSwName.IOS_XE));
```

Then you can just do:

```
if (IOS_ROUTERS.contains(request.getEquipmentInfo().getSoftwareName())) {
```